# ErrorUnknown column "..." in field list

Tags: java, mysql, database, jdbc, netbeans

So i have this problem with my database that i'm working on i have an error introducing information with my program that connects Mysql with Neatbeans using java.... the problem is when i'm

[Introducing information in my program](http://postimg.org/image/ho5oa71ud/)

if you need the info of my database and code  i'm gonna leave it here

```
    create database colorines;
use colorines;

    create table informacion(
    articulo varchar(50),
    departamento varchar(50),
    precio float,
    cantidad int
    )ENGINE=INNODB;
```

Database on MYSQL

```
   package jproject;

    /**
     *
     * @author KK
     */
    public class JProject {

        public static void main(String[] args) {

        }
    }
```

//This is the package called jproject.java the website put it in a same box the code but  this is separated from the next code

```
package jproject;




    import java.sql.*;
    import javax.swing.DefaultListModel;
    import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

     /* To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
     * and open the template in the editor.
     */

    /**
     *
     * @author KK
     */
    public class JProject2 extends javax.swing.JFrame {

        static Connection conn= null;/*metodos de tipo SQL para usar en la BD*/
        static Statement st=null;
        static ResultSet rs=null;


        DefaultListModel mod1= new DefaultListModel();
        DefaultListModel mod2= new DefaultListModel();
        DefaultListModel mod3= new DefaultListModel();
        DefaultListModel mod4= new DefaultListModel();


        /*datos de la BD para la conexion*/
        static String bd="colorines";
        static String login="root";
        static String pass="";
        static String url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/"+bd;

        /*Metodo para hacer la conexion a la bd*/
        public static Connection Enlace(Connection conn)throws SQLException
        {
            try
            {
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                conn= DriverManager.getConnection(url,login,pass);
            }
            catch(ClassNotFoundException c)
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null,c);
            }
            return conn;
        }

        /**
         * Creates new form Conecta
         */
        public JProject2() {
            initComponents();
            jTextField1.setText("");
            jTextField2.setText("");
            jTextField3.setText("");
            jTextField4.setText("");
            jTextField5.setText("");
            jTextField6.setText("");
            jList1.setModel(mod1);
            jList2.setModel(mod2);
            jList3.setModel(mod3);
            jList4.setModel(mod4);
            String cadena=""; 

            try
            {
            conn=Enlace(conn); /*creo la conexion con la base de datos*/
            st=conn.createStatement(); /*Especifico que hare una consulta sobre conn que contiene mi base de datos*/
            rs=st.executeQuery("select * from informacion"); /*guardo en rs result set, mi consulta de toda la tabla "informacion"*/

            while(rs.next()) /*mientras rs result set (contiene la tabla informacion), tenga datos para leer, sigue leyendo*/
            {

              /*cadena=cadena+rs.getString(1)+" - "+rs.getString(2)+" - "+rs.getString(3)+" - "+rs.getString(4)+"\n"; */ 
            mod1.addElement(rs.getString(1));
            mod2.addElement(rs.getString(2));
            mod3.addElement(rs.getString(3));
            mod4.addElement(rs.getString(4));

            }


            }
            catch (SQLException c)
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Error"+c.getMessage());
            }



        }



        /**
         * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
         * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
         * regenerated by the Form Editor.
         */
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
        private void initComponents() {

            jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
            jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
            jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
            jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
            jLabel4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
            jLabel5 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
            jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
            jTextField2 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
            jTextField3 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
            jTextField4 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
            jLabel6 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
            jLabel7 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
            jLabel8 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
            jLabel9 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
            jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
            jList1 = new javax.swing.JList();
            jScrollPane2 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
            jList2 = new javax.swing.JList();
            jScrollPane3 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
            jList3 = new javax.swing.JList();
            jScrollPane4 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
            jList4 = new javax.swing.JList();
            jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();
            jButton3 = new javax.swing.JButton();
            jTextField5 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
            jTextField6 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
            jScrollPane5 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
            jTextArea1 = new javax.swing.JTextArea();

            setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

            jLabel1.setText("          COLORINES ");

            jButton1.setText("GUARDAR");
            jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                    jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
                }
            });

            jLabel2.setText("ARTICULO");

            jLabel3.setText("MARCA");

            jLabel4.setText("PRECIO");

            jLabel5.setText("CANTIDAD");

            jTextField1.setText("jTextField1");
            jTextField1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                    jTextField1ActionPerformed(evt);
                }
            });

            jTextField2.setText("jTextField2");

            jTextField3.setText("jTextField3");

            jTextField4.setText("jTextField4");

            jLabel6.setText("CANTIDAD");

            jLabel7.setText("PRECIO");

            jLabel8.setText("MARCA");

            jLabel9.setText("ARTICULO");

            jList1.setModel(new javax.swing.AbstractListModel() {
                String[] strings = { "Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4", "Item 5" };
                public int getSize() { return strings.length; }
                public Object getElementAt(int i) { return strings[i]; }
            });
            jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jList1);

            jList2.setModel(new javax.swing.AbstractListModel() {
                String[] strings = { "Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4", "Item 5" };
                public int getSize() { return strings.length; }
                public Object getElementAt(int i) { return strings[i]; }
            });
            jScrollPane2.setViewportView(jList2);

            jList3.setModel(new javax.swing.AbstractListModel() {
                String[] strings = { "Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4", "Item 5" };
                public int getSize() { return strings.length; }
                public Object getElementAt(int i) { return strings[i]; }
            });
            jScrollPane3.setViewportView(jList3);

            jList4.setModel(new javax.swing.AbstractListModel() {
                String[] strings = { "Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4", "Item 5" };
                public int getSize() { return strings.length; }
                public Object getElementAt(int i) { return strings[i]; }
            });
            jScrollPane4.setViewportView(jList4);

            jButton2.setText("BUSCAR");
            jButton2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                    jButton2ActionPerformed(evt);
                }
            });

            jButton3.setText("BORRAR");
            jButton3.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                    jButton3ActionPerformed(evt);
                }
            });

            jTextField5.setText("jTextField5");

            jTextField6.setText("jTextField6");

            jTextArea1.setColumns(20);
            jTextArea1.setRows(5);
            jScrollPane5.setViewportView(jTextArea1);

            javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
            getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
            layout.setHorizontalGroup(
                layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 140, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addGap(281, 281, 281))
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(88, 88, 88)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addComponent(jTextField5, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 97, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addGap(116, 116, 116)
                            .addComponent(jButton2)))
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(jTextField6, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 116, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                    .addComponent(jButton3)
                    .addGap(144, 144, 144))
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(67, 67, 67)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                                .addComponent(jScrollPane5, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                        .addComponent(jLabel2)
                                        .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 121, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 45, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                    .addComponent(jTextField2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 92, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                    .addGap(52, 52, 52)
                                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                            .addComponent(jLabel4)
                                            .addGap(19, 19, 19))
                                        .addComponent(jTextField3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 71, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                            .addGap(45, 45, 45)
                                            .addComponent(jLabel5))
                                        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                            .addGap(28, 28, 28)
                                            .addComponent(jTextField4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 89, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                            .addGap(30, 30, 30)
                                            .addComponent(jButton1)))))
                            .addGap(34, 34, 34))
                        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                .addComponent(jLabel9)
                                .addComponent(jScrollPane1))
                            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                .addComponent(jScrollPane2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 126, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addComponent(jLabel8)
                                .addComponent(jLabel3))
                            .addGap(43, 43, 43)
                            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                .addComponent(jScrollPane3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 91, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addComponent(jLabel7))
                            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                    .addGap(43, 43, 43)
                                    .addComponent(jLabel6))
                                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                    .addGap(34, 34, 34)
                                    .addComponent(jScrollPane4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 71, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                            .addGap(87, 87, 87))))
            );
            layout.setVerticalGroup(
                layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 28, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                        .addComponent(jButton2)
                        .addComponent(jTextField5, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addComponent(jButton3)
                        .addComponent(jTextField6, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                        .addComponent(jLabel9, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 14, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addComponent(jLabel8)
                        .addComponent(jLabel7)
                        .addComponent(jLabel6))
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addComponent(jScrollPane2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addComponent(jScrollPane3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addComponent(jScrollPane4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addGap(26, 26, 26)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                        .addComponent(jLabel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 14, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addComponent(jLabel3)
                        .addComponent(jLabel4)
                        .addComponent(jLabel5))
                    .addGap(26, 26, 26)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                        .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addComponent(jTextField2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addComponent(jTextField3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addComponent(jTextField4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addComponent(jButton1))
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addComponent(jScrollPane5, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 73, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addContainerGap(35, Short.MAX_VALUE))
            );

            pack();
        }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
     try
            {
            conn=Enlace(conn); /*creo la conexion con la base de datos*/
            st=conn.createStatement(); /*Especifico que hare una consulta sobre conn que contiene mi base de datos*/
            st.execute("DELETE FROM informacion WHERE articulo='"+jTextField6.getText()+"'"); /*guardo en rs result set, mi consulta de toda la tabla "informacion"*/

            jTextField6.setText("");


            }
            catch (SQLException c)
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Error"+c.getMessage());
            }


            // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                        

    private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    String cadena="";

            try
            {
            conn=Enlace(conn); /*creo la conexion con la base de datos*/
            st=conn.createStatement(); /*Especifico que hare una consulta sobre conn que contiene mi base de datos*/
            rs=st.executeQuery("select informacion.articulo,informacion.departamento,informacion.precio,informacion.cantidad FROM informacion WHERE articulo='"+jTextField5.getText()+"';"); /*guardo en rs result set, mi consulta de toda la tabla "informacion"*/

            while(rs.next()) /*mientras rs result set (contiene la tabla lista), tenga datos para leer, sigue leyendo*/
            {

              cadena=cadena+rs.getString(1)+" "+rs.getString(2)+" "+rs.getString(3)+" "+rs.getString(4)+"\n";  
            /*mod1.addElement(rs.getString(1));
            mod2.addElement(rs.getString(2));
            mod3.addElement(rs.getString(3));
            mod4.addElement(rs.getString(4));
            */
            }
            jTextArea1.setText(cadena);

            }
            catch (SQLException c)
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Error"+c.getMessage());
            }


            // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                        

    private void jTextField1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                           

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    try
            {
            conn=Enlace(conn); /*creo la conexion con la base de datos*/
            st=conn.createStatement(); /*Especifico que hare una consulta sobre conn que contiene mi base de datos*/
            st.execute("INSERT INTO informacion VALUES ("+jTextField1.getText()+",'"+jTextField2.getText()+"','"+jTextField3.getText()+"','"+jTextField4.getText()+"');"); /*guardo en rs result set, mi consulta de toda la tabla "informacion"*/
            jTextField1.setText("");
            jTextField2.setText("");
            jTextField3.setText("");
            jTextField4.setText("");


            }
            catch (SQLException c)
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Error"+c.getMessage());
            }


            // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                        

        /**
         * @param args the command line arguments
         */
        public static void main(String args[]) {
            /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
            //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
            /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
             * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
             */
            try {
                for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                    if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                        javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                        break;
                    }
                }
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(JProject2.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
                java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(JProject2.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
                java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(JProject2.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(JProject2.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
            //</editor-fold>

            /* Create and display the form */
            java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

                public void run() {
                    new JProject2().setVisible(true);
                }
            });
        }
        // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
        private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
        private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
        private javax.swing.JButton jButton3;
        private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
        private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
        private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
        private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel4;
        private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel5;
        private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel6;
        private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel7;
        private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel8;
        private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel9;
        private javax.swing.JList jList1;
        private javax.swing.JList jList2;
        private javax.swing.JList jList3;
        private javax.swing.JList jList4;
        private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
        private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane2;
        private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane3;
        private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane4;
        private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane5;
        private javax.swing.JTextArea jTextArea1;
        private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
        private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField2;
        private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField3;
        private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField4;
        private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField5;
        private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField6;
        // This is JProject2.java                   
    }
```

This is JProject2.java, the code of the interface to send information to Mysql table via netbeans and a java connector between this 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is we probably need single quotes around the column values 
Because we are passing a string the correct functional code for your INSERT statement is:

```
"INSERT INTO informacion VALUES ('"+jTextField1.getText()+"', '"+jTextField2.getText()+"', "+jTextField3.getText()+", "+jTextField4.getText()+");"
```

And what you currently have in your jButton1ActionPerformed method is

```
"INSERT INTO informacion VALUES ("+jTextField1.getText()+",'"+jTextField2.getText()+"','"+jTextField3.getText()+"','"+jTextField4.getText()+"');"
```

which dpes not look right.

Alternatively you can use a  [PreparedStatement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) 
 A PreparedStatement is a special kind of Statement object with some useful features.

Advantages of PreparedStatement

1. Easy to insert parameters into the SQL statement.
2. Easy to reuse the PreparedStatement with new parameters.

You can use PreparedStatement instead of statement like below:

```
String insertTableSQL = "INSERT INTO informacion"
        + "(articulo , departamento , precio , cantidad ) VALUES"
        + "(?,?,?,?)";
PreparedStatement preparedStatement = conn.prepareStatement(insertTableSQL);
preparedStatement.setString(1, "jTextField1.getText()");
preparedStatement.setString(2, "jTextField2.getText()");
preparedStatement.setFloat(3, Float.parseFloat("jTextField3.getText()"));
preparedStatement.setInt(4, Integer.parseInt("jTextField4.getText()"));
// execute insert SQL stetement
preparedStatement .executeUpdate();
```

Comment: Concatenating values into a query string is never the right solution. If you point problems like this out, then please also suggest that people use prepared statements instead.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel thanks for the suggestion, I have made the suggested changes,, Will keep in mind next time..

Comment: Thanks! i make the changes you said and it worked perfectly, sorry if i hear kind of noob making this questions here, but as i said before, thanks for the help! really, thanks!

Comment: @karenlilianarobledo you are welcome.. There are no dumb questions.. Was a pleasure to help you